# How to fix "Failed to load IL2CPP" error in unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I am using Unity 2019.1.12f1, built a project for Android using IL2CPP.I chose ARMv7 and ARM64 in target architectures setting.I published it in the Play Store.But some devices are crashing.Error message is "Failed to load IL2CPP".

Comment: See [IL2CPP (android) build failing to load native library (DLL) on some devices.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/il2cpp-android-build-failing-to-load-native-library-dll-on-some-devices.367399/) **For your Failed to extract resources needed by Il2CPP** it *maybe* **ERROR MESSAGE WHEN LOCAL STORAGE IS FULL** see [issuetracker.unity3d.com issue 1171893](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/custom-failed-to-extract-resources-needed-by-il2cpp-error-message-when-local-storage-is-full)

Comment: No. Always error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is during the install, It is hard to notice the dropdown >   that lets you check the boxes for the ndk install.. and when you do not check it..it uses the old version 16b instead and doesn't let you upgrade it to anything higher through preferences manually.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Changed to .NET 4.x and the problem solved!
Unity Ver 2019.4.5f1